tikz-3dplot projections on planes are distorted
Note: As correctly pointed out in the comments, this post was inspired by this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726538/319072.
I'm trying to take the projections of an object drawn in tikz-3dplot on the coordinate planes.
I am running into a problem where when I remove the x, y and z coordinates for each projection, it causes the projection to become squished on the  plane.
The projections are obviously inaccurate, and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.
This example is rather long, but it is the minimal necessary to show a sphere and its projections on the planes.
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Vn}{15}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{2*\Vn}{3*\Vn}

\foreach \Vt in {0,0.2,...,4}{
\draw[ultra thin] (\Vt,0,0) -- (\Vt,4,0);
\draw[ultra thin] (0,\Vt,0) -- (4,\Vt,0);

\draw[ultra thin] (\Vt,0,0) -- (\Vt,0,4);
\draw[ultra thin] (0,0,\Vt) -- (4,0,\Vt);

\draw[ultra thin] (0,\Vt,0) -- (0,\Vt,4);
\draw[ultra thin] (0,0,\Vt) -- (0,4,\Vt);

}
\foreach \Vi in {0,30,...,330}{

\path[tdplot_rotated_coords,spath/save=pathname]
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(0)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(0)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz)
 foreach \t in {30,60,...,330}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(\t)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(\t)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz) 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(\t+30)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(\t+30)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz)};
\draw[spath/use={pathname,transform={shift={(2,2,2)}}}];

\path[tdplot_rotated_coords,spath/save=pathname]
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(0)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(0)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(0)}} (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz)
 foreach \t in {30,60,...,330}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\t)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(\t)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(\t)}} -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz) 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\t+30)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(\t+30)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(\t)}} -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz)};
\draw[spath/use={pathname,transform={shift={(2,2,2)}}}];
}


\foreach \Vi in {0,30,...,330}{

\path[tdplot_rotated_coords,spath/save=pathname]
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(0)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(0)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0)
 foreach \t in {30,60,...,330}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(\t)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(\t)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0) 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(\t+30)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(\t+30)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0)};
\draw[spath/use={pathname,transform={shift={(2,2,0)}}}];

\path[tdplot_rotated_coords,spath/save=pathname]
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(0)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(0)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(0)}} (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0)
 foreach \t in {30,60,...,330}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\t)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(\t)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(\t)}} -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0) 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\t+30)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(\t+30)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(\t)}} -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0)};
\draw[spath/use={pathname,transform={shift={(2,2,0)}}}];
}

\foreach \Vi in {0,30,...,330}{

\path[tdplot_rotated_coords,spath/save=pathname]
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(0)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(0)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} (\tdplotresx,0,\tdplotresz)
 foreach \t in {30,60,...,330}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(\t)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(\t)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} -- (\tdplotresx,0,\tdplotresz) 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(\t+30)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(\t+30)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} -- (\tdplotresx,0,\tdplotresz)};
\draw[spath/use={pathname,transform={shift={(2,0,2)}}}];

\path[tdplot_rotated_coords,spath/save=pathname]
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(0)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(0)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(0)}} (\tdplotresx,0,\tdplotresz)
 foreach \t in {30,60,...,330}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\t)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(\t)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(\t)}} -- (\tdplotresx,0,\tdplotresz) 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\t+30)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(\t+30)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(\t)}} -- (\tdplotresx,0,\tdplotresz)};
\draw[spath/use={pathname,transform={shift={(2,0,2)}}}];
}

\foreach \Vi in {0,30,...,330}{

\path[tdplot_rotated_coords,spath/save=pathname]
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(0)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(0)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} (0,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz)
 foreach \t in {30,60,...,330}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(\t)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(\t)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} -- (0,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz) 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(\t+30)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(\t+30)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} -- (0,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz)};
\draw[spath/use={pathname,transform={shift={(0,2,2)}}}];

\path[tdplot_rotated_coords,spath/save=pathname]
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(0)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(0)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(0)}} (0,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz)
 foreach \t in {30,60,...,330}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\t)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(\t)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(\t)}} -- (0,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz) 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\t+30)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(\t+30)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(\t)}} -- (0,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz)};
\draw[spath/use={pathname,transform={shift={(0,2,2)}}}];
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



When you use other peoples code you should give a reference. Also When asking this question it would be nice for others to see where it was partly solved, to avoid repeat work.

spath3 is counter productive here. You use main coordinates in the rotated system and over complicates things.

My apologies @hpekristiansen. I was legitimately under the impression that this wasn't your property, but will add the reference. I will also link to your other answer. No mal-intent on my part. Just ignorance.

It is not my property at all - very far from it. -but you did use my code, so it is always nice to link to it.

I understand. In the future I will be more prudent. Obviously, I have no intention of passing this off as my own, as you did in fact teach me this. I didn't realize, and I'm sorry.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Vn}{15}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{2*\Vn}{3*\Vn}
\coordinate (Shift) at (2,2,2);
\tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(Shift)}

\foreach \Vt in {0,0.2,...,4}{
\draw[ultra thin] (\Vt,0,0) -- (\Vt,4,0);
\draw[ultra thin] (0,\Vt,0) -- (4,\Vt,0);
\draw[ultra thin] (\Vt,0,0) -- (\Vt,0,4);
\draw[ultra thin] (0,0,\Vt) -- (4,0,\Vt);
\draw[ultra thin] (0,\Vt,0) -- (0,\Vt,4);
\draw[ultra thin] (0,0,\Vt) -- (0,4,\Vt);
}


\foreach \Vi in {-90,-70,...,90}{
\draw[tdplot_rotated_coords]
({0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(0)},{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(0)},{0.5*sin(\Vi)})
 foreach \t in {20,40,...,340}{ 
-- ({0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(\t)},{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(\t)},{0.5*sin(\Vi)})
} -- cycle;
\draw[tdplot_rotated_coords]
({0.5*cos(0)*cos(\Vi)},{0.5*cos(0)*sin(\Vi)},{0.5*sin(0)})
 foreach \t in {20,40,...,340}{ 
-- ({0.5*cos(\t)*cos(\Vi)},{0.5*cos(\t)*sin(\Vi)},{0.5*sin(\t)})
} -- cycle;
}


\foreach \Vi in {-90,-60,...,90}{
\draw[red, shift={(0,2,2)}]
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(0)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(0)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} (0,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz)
 foreach \t in {20,40,...,340}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(\t)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(\t)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} -- (0,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz)
} -- cycle;
\draw[red, shift={(0,2,2)}]
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(0)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(0)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(0)}} (0,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz)
 foreach \t in {20,40,...,340}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\t)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(\t)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(\t)}} -- (0,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz)
} -- cycle;
}

\foreach \Vi in {-90,-60,...,90}{
\draw[teal, shift={(2,0,2)}]
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(0)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(0)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} (\tdplotresx,0,\tdplotresz)
 foreach \t in {20,40,...,340}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(\t)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(\t)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} -- (\tdplotresx,0,\tdplotresz)
} -- cycle;
\draw[teal, shift={(2,0,2)}]
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(0)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(0)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(0)}} (\tdplotresx,0,\tdplotresz)
 foreach \t in {20,40,...,340}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\t)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(\t)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(\t)}} -- (\tdplotresx,0,\tdplotresz)
} -- cycle;
}

\foreach \Vi in {-90,-60,...,90}{
\draw[blue, shift={(2,2,0)}]
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(0)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(0)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0)
 foreach \t in {20,40,...,340}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\Vi)*cos(\t)}{0.5*cos(\Vi)*sin(\t)}{0.5*sin(\Vi)}} -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0)
} -- cycle;
\draw[blue, shift={(2,2,0)}]
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(0)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(0)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(0)}} (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0)
 foreach \t in {20,40,...,340}{ 
\pgfextra{\tdplottransformrotmain{0.5*cos(\t)*cos(\Vi)}{0.5*cos(\t)*sin(\Vi)}{0.5*sin(\t)}} -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,0)
} -- cycle;
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


